# Is it possible to have a weighted graph (integer weights are also ok) where the max flow can be obtained in a non unique way?

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

My question is simple: given a DAG $G=(V,E,C)$ where $V$ is the set of nodes, $E \in V \times V$ is the set of edges,$C$ is a weight function that associate to each link a number that represent the capacity of the link.
By applying the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm i can find the max flow, now my doubt is: is this max flow unique? Is there another network flows configuration such that i can obtain the same maximum flow? 
In few words...is the solution of the min cut-max flow theorem unique?
thanks to everybody
Gianni

Comment: How about a square with one source and one sink in opposite corners and every edge the same capacity?